# In node.js how to check whether the particular write stream is opened or not

Tags: node.js, stream

Before opening the stream need to check whether the stream is already opened or not

```
var fs=require('fs');
var stream=fs.createWriteStream(filePath, {flags: 'a'});
stream.on('open',function(){


});
```

Answer (score 0):

the stream will emit `open` when its opened since this is async there is no way of telling when it will emit, you can even write something like

```
var _path = "text.txt";
var stream1 = fs.createWriteStream(_path,{flags:"a"});
var stream2 = fs.createWriteStream(_path,{flags:"a"});
var stream3 = fs.createWriteStream(_path,{flags:"a"});
var streamN = fs.createWriteStream(_path,{flags:"a"});
```

and all will emit `open` event when their are ready.

if you dump with `console.log` one of the objects when open is emitted you will see an object with many properties such as `_writableState` where write state is preserved.

one not so awesome way is try something like below

```
var _path = "text.txt";
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(_path,{flags:"a"});
var stream2 = fs.createWriteStream(_path,{flags:"a"});

var lock = false; // try switching this , when opened and on other events to get the flow.
```